# Filter tagged threads in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I have a big issue with Thunderbird, I need to process a lot of emails coming from request tracking system.

Since only few of those apply to me personally, I tag these threads with appropriate tags.

The issue now is that I would like to filter out threads, that do apply to me and those that I haven't tagged yet.

I'm unable to do this, because new emails keep arriving into the already existing threads, and of course, these new emails don't get the tags.

Basically I would need some sort of filtering rule, that would apply not to a specific message, but the master message in the thread.

Is there some possibility to create such filters, or is there some other facility, that would allow me to do the same? Tags are great, since they are actually saved into the messages and correctly sync across multiple machines when using IMAP.

Comment: What’s message tagging? IMAP does not have such feature.

Comment: @kinokijuf http://kb.mozillazine.org/Tags

Comment: Wow, I didn’t know about IMAP keywords. My provider does not seem to support them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use thunderbird addon [FiltaQuilla](http://mesquilla.com/extensions/filtaquilla/).

I have something close in my extension 
[FiltaQuilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/), which is a search term for the tag of the thread head. So 
what you should be able to do is to create a virtual folder using that 
term, then manually tag the thread head. Then all of the children of 
that thread should also also appear in the virtual folder.

I also have a search term "tag of thread messages" that will scan the 
thread for nearby messages, and add the message to a search if it finds 
a tag in any of those messages.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome. But doesn't work with online search.